# Grails many-to-many unknown column when sorting

Tags: mysql, grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I came across an odd error when using GORM default sorting on hasMany. I used default sorting often in one-to-many and never had issues.

**Please note that the code runs perfectly when I remove the mapping clause in both classes.** But I really want default sorting in the Database. I know that I can also fix this with .sort{ it.id }

This are my domain classes:

```
abstract class Product {

    String nr
    String name
    static hasMany = [requirements:Requirement]

    static mapping = {
        requirements sort: 'id'
}


class Requirement {

    String name
    String imageName

    static hasMany = [products:Product]
    static belongsTo = Product

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false, blank:false)
        imageName(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort 'id'
    }
}
```

Now, when I call

```
def product = Product.findByNr("test")
log.debug pr.requirements
```

I get

```
2015-05-28 17:58:03,374 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Unknown column 'requiremen0_.id' in 'order clause'
Error |
2015-05-28 17:58:03,455 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLSyntaxErrorException occurred when processing request: [GET] /testDb
Unknown column 'requiremen0_.id' in 'order clause'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Unknown column 'requiremen0_.id' in 'order clause'
```

Comment: I've personally never seen the `sort 'id'` mapping on the many side like that. I've only ever used it on the "owning" side. If you remove the sort from Requirement, does it work?

Comment: Yes. I get the same error when I remove the sort from Requirement. I also tried to sort by 'name' bit it's the same error but with the error message Unknown column 'requiremen0_.name'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sort should be applied to a field of the current class, not a field of an associated class: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html **

The idea of sort it to have the current queried class sorted:

> Customizes the default property to sort by for query results. **

For example you can sort Products by it's name, but how do you sort Products by the ids of a set of related Requirements? IMHO it doesn't make much sense.

Try remove the requirements sort: 'id' from Product.

BTW do you have any concrete subclasses of the abstract Product?